# Is there any way to convert a static byte array to a BufReader?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to play a sound using the [rodio crate](https://docs.rs/rodio/latest/rodio/index.html).  Following the example I am attempting to do it like so:

```
fn play() {
    let (_stream, stream_handle) = OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
    
    // Get the bytes of the sample AIF file
    let bytes = include_bytes!("sound.aif");

    // Decode that sound file into a source
    let source = Decoder::new(bytes).unwrap();
    // Play the sound directly on the device
    stream_handle.play_raw(source.convert_samples());
}
```

Unlike the example, I want to embed the bytes in the binary, rather than loading them from a file.

When I attempt this, I get the following error:

> The trait bound `Seek` is not satisfied

Because `bytes` does not implement `Seek`, which is required by `Decoder::new`.

It seems the types implementing this trait include:

```
             &mut S
             &std::fs::File
             Box<S>
             BufReader<R>
             BufWriter<W>
             either::Either<L, R>
             std::fs::File
             std::io::Cursor<T>
             std::io::Empty
```

Is there a way to instantiate any of these from raw bytes?

Comment: `std::io::Cursor` is just what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Cursor<&[u8]>](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Cursor.html):

> A Cursor wraps an in-memory buffer and provides it with a Seek implementation.
>
> Cursors are used with in-memory buffers, anything implementing AsRef<[u8]>, to allow them to implement Read and/or Write, allowing these buffers to be used anywhere you might use a reader or writer that does actual I/O.

An example would be something like this:

```
use std::io::Cursor;
use std::io::Seek;

// Stubbed out
fn decode(_: impl Seek) {}

fn main() {
    let bytes: &'static [u8] = b"test data";
    let cursor = Cursor::new(bytes);
    decode(cursor);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec2ddc27de53bc815b71a77ae37b1fb9)